# HAProxy: change backend as path?

Tags: haproxy

I am new to haproxy
Is it possible for haproxy to using a backend when using the subpath?
e.g.

```
test.app.com/a/  > appa.example.com:5000/
test.app.com/b/  > appb.example.com:5001/
```

so that

```
http://test.app.com/a/index.html >  appa.example.com:5000/index.html
http://test.app.com/b/testing/ > appb.example.com:5001/testing/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. ACLs for path, like `path_beg` and `use_backend` to route traffic as requested. In backends modify path with `http-request set-path`.
Simplified example below:

```
frontend http
  bind *:80
  acl url_a path_beg -i /a/
  acl url_b path_beg -i /b/
  use_backend backend-a if url_a
  use_backend backend-b if url_b

backend backend-a
  http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/a/,/,g)]
  server a appa.example.com:5000

backend backend-b
  http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/b/,/,g)]
  server b appb.example.com:5001
```

Comment: I only can get this to work on first page. For example, if there is an login page on appa.example.com:5000 and it will change to appa.example.com:5000/login after login, the page will change to test.app.com/login and  unable to access.

Comment: Well that's clear because your request was to use a backend based on path and the path is changed to '/login'. You should tell the backend which creates the redirect to add '/a' or 'b/' to the path. You can also use haproxy to add /a to the respone http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20replace-header "http-response replace-value Location test.app.com(/login) test.app.com/a\1"

Comment: um... seems I can't make it work due to the link to login is inside the form in content of the page but not in header part. so if I change the /login to appa only, appb will having problem if it include /login also.
May be I consider using different subdomain for easier work.
Thanks.